# Any know memory leak with using MediaElement control?

Tags: wpf

I'm using MediaElement control in an application, does this control leak memory over a period of time?

Comment: Can you add the code behind to the question. The memory leak can be caused by it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement" Height="720" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Visibility="Hidden" IsMuted="True" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment">
    </MediaElement>
```

Source defined is in the framework loaded event. Below is the code.

```
                <Storyboard>
                    <MediaTimeline Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Styles/Video/DYK.mp4"  Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
```